# Reset button not working

Tags: java, swing, reset

I would be greatfull if anyone could help me with my code. I have a project that involved an artificial lifeform( a bug ) that eats food and avoids obstacles. So far i have food randomly generated on the map. When i hit the reset button all the food dissapears and the bug goes back to the first square and is not randomised. Can anyone tell me why? Also how do i stop bugs and food being put onto the same panel sometimes. Any help would be great, thanks!
    package Javaproject;

```
import java.lang.Math.*; 
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.awt.GridLayout; 
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent; 
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 
import java.io.File; 
import java.util.Random; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream; 
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem; 
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip; 
import javax.swing.BorderFactory; 
import javax.swing.ImageIcon; 
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import javax.swing.JFrame; 
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 
import javax.swing.JPanel; 
import javax.swing.JSlider; 
import javax.swing.JSpinner; 
import javax.swing.JTextField; 
import javax.swing.JToolBar; 
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel; 
import javax.swing.Timer; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent; 
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener; 



@SuppressWarnings("serial") 
public class JumpinJackFlash extends JPanel implements ActionListener, ChangeListener { 
private JPanel gridPanel;  //the panel containing the 2D grid 
private JPanel cells[][]; //the cells of the 2D grid 

private JToolBar toolBar; 
private JButton jb_start, jb_stop, jb_reset; 

private JTextField jtf_info; 

private Timer timer; 
private int speed; //cycles per second 
private int cycleNum; 
private JSpinner jspin_speed; 

private final static String RELPATHICONS = "icons" + File.separator; //relative path to icons folder 
private final static String RELPATHSOUNDS = "sounds" + File.separator; //relative path to sounds folder 

private static Random ran = new Random(); 
private static final int hsize=10; 
private static final int vsize=10; 


//the moving item: 
private JLabel jack; 
private int jack_x, jack_y; 
private File boingSoundFile; 

private JLabel Food; 
private int food_x, food_y; 

private static JSlider slider() { 
    JSlider slider; 
    slider = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL, 0, 20, 0); 
    slider.setMajorTickSpacing(5); 
    slider.setPaintTicks(true); 
    return slider; 
} 
/** 
 * The constructor 
 */


public JumpinJackFlash(){ 
    gridPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(hsize, vsize)); 
    cells = new JPanel[hsize][vsize]; 
    for(int i=0; i<hsize; i++){ 
        for(int j=0; j<vsize; j++){ 
            cells[i][j] = new JPanel(); 
            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.white); 
            cells[i][j].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black)); 
            gridPanel.add(cells[i][j]); 

        }    
    } 

    //{ 
    // cells[i][j] = Food 
    // } 


    jack = new JLabel(getImageIcon("download.gif")); 
    boingSoundFile = new File(RELPATHSOUNDS+File.separator+"boing.wav"); 
    //init position within the 2D grid 

    int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 
    int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 
    jack_x = rand1;  
    jack_y= rand2; 
    cells[jack_x][jack_y].add(jack); 


    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) 
    { 
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 
        int rand4 = (int) (Math.random() * 9); 
        food_x = rand3;  
        food_y= rand4; 
        cells[food_x][food_y].add(new JLabel(getImageIcon("food.gif"))); 
    } 

    //The toolbar 
    toolBar = new JToolBar(); 
    jb_start = new JButton(getImageIcon("start.gif")); 
    jb_start.setToolTipText("start"); 
    jb_stop = new JButton(getImageIcon("stop.gif")); 
    jb_stop.setToolTipText("stop"); 
    jb_reset = new JButton(getImageIcon("back.gif")); 
    jb_reset.setToolTipText("reset"); 
    toolBar.add(jb_start); 
    toolBar.add(jb_stop); 
    toolBar.add(jb_reset); 

    //Some text for info 
    jtf_info = new JTextField("cycle "+"<"+cycleNum+">"); 
    jtf_info.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY); 

    //The speed 
    speed = 1; //init speed of the animation (1 cycle per second) 
    SpinnerNumberModel jsm = new SpinnerNumberModel(speed,1,50,1); 
    jspin_speed = new JSpinner(jsm); 
    JLabel jlb_speed = new JLabel("Speed", JLabel.CENTER); 
    JPanel speedPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
    speedPanel.add(jlb_speed, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    speedPanel.add(jspin_speed, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    speedPanel.add(new JLabel("(steps per second)", JLabel.CENTER), BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    gridPanel.add(slider(), BorderLayout.EAST); 

    //A panel for the toolbar 
    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout()); 
    topPanel.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.WEST); 
    topPanel.add(speedPanel, BorderLayout.EAST); 

    //Set the layout of the main panel 
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); 
    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); 
    add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
    add(jtf_info, BorderLayout.SOUTH); 

    //Init the timer and register 'this' as listener 
    timer = new Timer(1000/speed, this); //create a new Timer object and register 'this' as 
                                         //listener for the periodic Timer events 
    timer.setInitialDelay(500); //in msec 
    cycleNum = 0; 

    //Register 'this' listener for the events generated by the jbuttons  
    //and by the Timer object. 
    jb_start.addActionListener(this); 
    jb_stop.addActionListener(this); 
    jb_reset.addActionListener(this); 

    //Register 'this' listener for the events generated by the jspinner 
    jspin_speed.addChangeListener(this); 
} 

/** 
 * The call back method for the events generated by the jbuttons  
 * and for the periodic events generated by the timer. 
 */
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
    if(e.getSource() == timer){ 
        cycleNum++;           //next step (cycle) of the synchronous animation 
        gridContent_update(); //update the content of the grid 
        this.repaint();       //repaint the view 

    } else if(e.getSource() == jb_start) { 
        speed = ((SpinnerNumberModel)jspin_speed.getModel()).getNumber().intValue(); 
        timer.setDelay(1000/speed); 
        timer.start(); //start the animation by starting the timer 

    } else if(e.getSource() == jb_stop) { 
        timer.stop(); 

    } else if(e.getSource() == jb_reset) { 
        timer.stop(); 
        cycleNum = 0; 
        gridContent_reset(); 
        this.repaint(); 

    } else { 
        //System.out.println("##### unknown event source #####"); 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * The call back method for the events generated by the jspinner, 
 * which is used to change the animation speed. 
 */
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) { 
    if(e.getSource() == jspin_speed) { 
        speed = ((SpinnerNumberModel)jspin_speed.getModel()).getNumber().intValue(); 
        timer.setDelay(1000/speed); 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * Set new random coordinates for the moving item.<br> 
 * It check if the passed new coordinates are valid,  
 * i.e. within the grid dimensions. 
 *   
 * @param coordX 
 * @param coordY 
 * @return true if new valid coordinates have been set. 
 */
private boolean moveJackTo(int coordX, int coordY){ 
    if((coordX>=0) && (coordX<hsize) && (coordY>=0) && (coordY<vsize)){ 
        if((coordX!=jack_x) || (coordY!=jack_y)){ //valid new coordinates 
            cells[jack_x][jack_y].removeAll(); //remove jack from start pos 
            jack_x = coordX; 
            jack_y = coordY; 
            cells[jack_x][jack_y].add(jack); //add jack to dest pos  

            return true; 

        } 
    } 
    return false; //the coordinates have not been changed 
} 

/** 
 * This method is used to change the content of the 2D grid, 
 * i.e. the position of the moving item jack. 
 */
private void gridContent_update(){ 
    boolean moved = false; 
    while(!moved){ //repeat until new valid coordinates have been set 
        int x = jack_x; 
        int y = jack_y; 






        Random rn = new Random(); 
        int answer = rn.nextInt(4) + 1; 
        switch(answer){ 
        case(1):  
        { 
        y++; break; 
        } 
        case(2):  
        { 
        y--; break; 
        } 
        case(3):  
        { 
        x++; break; 
        } 
        case(4):  
        { 
         x--; break; 
        } 

        } 

        moved = moveJackTo(x, y); 
    } 

    jtf_info.setText("cycle <"+cycleNum+">"); 

    this.validate(); //should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified  
} 

/** 
 * This method is used to reset the content of the 2D grid, 
 * i.e. the initial position of the moving item jack. 
 */
private void gridContent_reset(){ 
    for (int i = 0; i < hsize; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < vsize; j++) { 
            cells[i][j].removeAll(); 
            cells[i][j].setBackground(Color.white); 
        } 
    } 

    //init position 
    jack_x=0; 
    jack_y=0; 
    cells[jack_x][jack_y].add(jack); 

    cycleNum = 0; 
    jtf_info.setText("cycle <"+cycleNum+">"); 

    this.validate(); //should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified  
} 


/** 
 * Return a ImageIcon with the given icon or generate an error message. 
 */
private static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String iconFilename) { 
    ImageIcon theIcon; 
    File theImage = new File(RELPATHICONS + iconFilename); 
    if (theImage.isFile()) { 
        theIcon = new ImageIcon(theImage.getAbsolutePath()); 

    } else { 
        // show an error message and quit 
        theIcon = null; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error - file not found: "
                + iconFilename); 
        System.exit(-1); 
    } 
    return (theIcon); 
} 

/** 
 * Return a ImageIcon with the given icon or a default image 
 */
private static ImageIcon getImageIcon(String iconFilename, String std_iconFilename) { 
    ImageIcon theIcon; 
    File theImage = new File(RELPATHICONS + iconFilename); 
    if (theImage.isFile()) { 
        theIcon = new ImageIcon(theImage.getAbsolutePath()); 

    } else { 
        theImage = new File(RELPATHICONS + std_iconFilename); 
        theIcon = new ImageIcon(theImage.getAbsolutePath()); 
    } 
    return (theIcon); 
} 

/** 
 * play a sound 
 * @param theSoundFile 
 */
private static void playSound(File theSoundFile) { 
    try { 
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip(); 
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(theSoundFile); 
        clip.open(ais); 
        clip.loop(0); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e); 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
} 

/** 
 * Create the GUI and show it. For thread safety, this method should be 
 * invoked by the event-dispatching thread. 
 */
private static void createAndShowGUI() { 
    // Create the container 


    JFrame wm_frame = new JFrame("Synchronous Animation"); 

    // Quit the application when this frame is closed: 
    wm_frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    // Create and add the content panel 
    JumpinJackFlash wm_panel = new JumpinJackFlash(); 
    wm_frame.add(wm_panel);     // OR frame.setContentPane(panel); 

    // Display the window 
    wm_frame.pack(); // adapt the frame size to its content 
    wm_frame.setLocation(10, 10); // in pixels 
    wm_frame.setVisible(true); // Now the frame will appear on screen 
} 

public static void main (String args[]){ 
    // Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread: 
    // creating and showing this application's GUI. 
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() { 
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        } 
    }); 
} 

}
```

Comment: What have your attempts to debug this code as it runs, using a debugger, yielded? You must first find the error before dumping a ton of code here and asking others to find it for you.

Comment: In your "reset" logic, you never restart the `timer`.  As to the second part, you're going to need to maintain some kind of `List` of available objects and ensure that whenever you create more, it checks to the list to see what space is available

Comment: For the love of God, please clean up your code and only post meaningful code snippets on your questions

Comment: What you really want to do is to refactor your code so as to separate the logic and the GUI parts into separate testable classes since right now you're struggling with one huge God-class. This will make debugging, modifying and enhancing much easier to do.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, when the "rest" button is clicked, you should be `restarting` the `Timer` to start over again.

```
} else if (e.getSource() == jb_reset) {
    timer.stop();
    cycleNum = 0;
    gridContent_reset();
    // Restart the timer...
    timer.start();
    this.repaint();
}
```

As to the second half of your question, basically, you need to check if the `JPanel` at `cells[x][y]` contains any children and keep randomizing the x/y values into it doesn't (or you hit some kind of limit, so as to prevent the possibility of an infinite loop)

Another approach might be to randomize a list (possibly containing the `JPanel` for each cell) and simply pop off the first element when you want to add food and add it back in when no food exists (within that cell)

You should break you code down so that, at the very least, the model and view are separated.

The model would contain information about the state of the game, where as the view would be responsible for rendering it.  This will help simplify much of the logic as you shouldn't care about what is going on the screen when you want to determine where to place food.